# Attempted calculation of the probability to win a game.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I'm playing the game ["Pepper Panic"](http://gamewise.co/games/51930/Pepper-Panic-Saga) and the goal is to create two pepper panics. I noted down some ten results by the numbers I obtained ($0$ or $1$). I obtained a mean of $0.4$ and a standard deviation of $0.51$. If I take as a hypthesis that the distribution is normal and I calculate the probability for the result be $\geq 2$ I get $0.000852689$ which is very very low, since I have already won the game after some twenty times. What is wrong here?

Comment: Your hypothesis ($X \sim \mathcal N(0.4, 0.51)$) must thus be wrong. This is very likely because you only used ten tries and you didn't capture the "result" (You captured $0,1$ and want to know if $0,1 \ge 2$?)

Comment: That's what I tought too. I think the reason is that there are only two values. In the classical approximation by the discrete Bernoulli distribution there are more than two values and moreover the distribution is symmetric. Here there is no symmetry at all. Should I use a Poisson distribution instead (because we can't go "under 0")?

Comment: You should gather a lot of data points so that your results are all seen (or at least more of them, say until your result is as high as $10$ at least once) and then look at the points to see what distribution they might follow.

Comment: I'll do that and update my question then, thanks. But that could take a couple of  days because the number of "lives" are restricted in time.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question for that and tag it with [tag:statistics] as well. It may be useful to delete this question since there really is no fruitful answer to it.

Comment: Ok I'll do that. Have you an idea of how much sample to take?

Comment: As many as you possibly can. I throw in a 1000 for a start :D

Comment: 1000 would be good but is probably excessive ~ 30-50 will give normal(ish) results due to the Central Limit Theorem irrespective of the underlying distribution.